# Display column result  as row result  php

Tags: php

I am sure the title is not even right on this one. 
Here is the issue , I have **3** columns and **6** results 
that are displayed like this

```
Column1           Column2             Column3
result1           result3             result5
result2           result4             result6
```

but need them like this

```
Column1           Column2             Column3
result1           result2             result3
result4           result5             result6
```

my array holds all 6 results and so far I see I need to pick  every 0 and 2nd to be displayed in column1 and continue( array starts at 0).

the code is pretty large but the main part for switching results is here

```
$count = count($result);
for ($result = 0; $result < $count; $result++) {
                    $getorder= "";
                    if ($count != 1) {
                        if ($result == 0) $getorder= "first";
                        if ($result == $count - 1) $getorder= "last";
                    }


    echo '<div class="'.$getorder.'width'.intval(100 / $count).'">'.$mycolumn[$result].'</div>';
}
```

so this here should have some kind of division. Here is just dumb example

```
$mycolumn[$result % X == X]
```

i hope I did not confuse you and you get the idea.  If you ask yourself why i don't just do rows instead columns , answer is complete css reconstructions. whit this here figured out I can target the results and keep columns and css as they are

Comment: Why don't you use a `<table>`? This is exactly what they are used for.

Comment: cmon tables?  no way , must stay with divs

Comment: Why? Tables are not bad when used for tabular data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `($result / 3)` since you can have [seriuous rounding problem](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).
Since to me it's not very clear the name of your vars I post you a php generic code and it is:

```
echo '<div class="result">';
for($i = 0; $i < $columnNum; $i++)
{
   echo '<div class="column">';
   for($j = $i; $j < $resultNum; $j += $columnNum)
      echo '<label class="value">' . array[j] . "</label>";
   echo '</div>';
}
echo '</div>';
```

Just change the vars name with your needs and this is the solution to your problem.

Comment: this is not answer, but comment

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski Absolutely wrong. This is the solution to his problem. How can be a comment? If the OP change the var names this will do exactly what he wants to do.

Comment: THANK YOU! joomla man @AurelioDeRosa  peter was right also but I dont understand what the issue would be with his part ,  this simply did it $mycolumn[($result / 3) + $result  % 3]  do you think is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
$mycolumn[intval($result / 3) + intval(($result % 3) * $count / 3)]
```

Demo http://codepad.viper-7.com/hdSi6b

Working flawlessly.

You can change whole code as AurelioDeRosa said.

Comment: Since you assert that my code can be used and so it's right, I don't understand even more the downvote.